# Overflow auto not working with position absolute

Tags: html, css

In the below code,

1. I have a parent div (.parent) and three child divs(.child1, .child2 , .child3).
2. .child1 has a button clicking on which a table is displayed.

Requirement -

1. .child2 should overlap .child3
2. .child2 should be horizontally scrollable

Issue -

setting overflow-x with position absolute is not working.

How to make this table scrollable as well as make it overlap all the divs that are below it ?

Attempt -

```js
$('#expand').click(function(){
    $('.child2').toggle()
});
```

```css
.child2{
    /* position: absolute;
    z-index: 2; */
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.child3 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1" style="background-color: aqua; width: 50%;">
        <button id="expand">EXPAND</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child2" style="display: none;">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>MarkMarkMarkMarkMarkMarkMark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="child3" style="background-color: coral; width: 50%;">
        CHILD3
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow-x` does not work unless you have a width, for some reason. If the element is not absolutely positioned, the default is that the width is `auto`, however, when it is absolutely positioned, it messes up slightly and it takes up all the width it needs, no questions asked.

So you can sort this out by adding `width: 100%` to your `.child2`

```js
$('#expand').click(function(){
    $('.child2').toggle()
});
```

```css
.child2{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.child3 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1" style="background-color: aqua; width: 50%;">
        <button id="expand">EXPAND</button>
    </div>
    <div class="child2" style="display: none;">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>MarkMarkMarkMarkMarkMarkMark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="child3" style="background-color: coral; width: 50%;">
        CHILD3
    </div>
</div>
```